# Change button text on toggle jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, toggle

Simple question why that code change text in button only for Hide details and never back to Show details?

```js
$CandidateList.on('click', '.detail-button', function () {
    toggleDetails($(this));
});

//toggle details
function toggleDetails($btn) {
    $btn.next('table').toggle(480);
    if ($btn.text('Show details')) {
        $btn.text('Hide details')
    }
    else
        $btn.text('Show details')
}
```

Comment: `if($btn.text().trim() == "Show details")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be *getting* the text, not *setting* it like you are right now:

```
$CandidateList.on('click', '.detail-button', function () {
    toggleDetails($(this));
});

//toggle details
function toggleDetails($btn) {
    $btn.next('table').toggle(480);
    $btn.text() == "Show details" ? $btn.text("Hide details") : $btn.text("Show details");
}
```

Comment: $btn.text() === "Show details" ? $btn.text("Hide details") : $btn.text("Show details");

Works fine thx ;)

Comment: No worries @BartoszKolej

Answer (score 0):

Your toggle in the conditional is setting the text rather than retrieving it's true value.

```
function toggleDetails($btn) {
    $btn.next('table').toggle(480);
    $btn.text($btn.text() == 'Show details' ? 'Hide details' : 'Show details')
}
```